# React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack

Estoy tomando un tutorial para aprender `React JS`, todo iba bien, hace días que pude correr un ejemplo, sencillo, llevando a cabo una configuración básica recomendada, mas unos complementos mas que le agrego para reconocer la versión de `Javascript`.

Los errores son los siguientes

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> The above error occurred in one of your React components: Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Cabe aclarar que los errores aparecen en el archivo `bundle.js`, el cual se usa para que se almacene el código generado a través de `webpack`

[image: Errores mulriples en react js]

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: estructure]

#### package.json

`{
  "name": "prueba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"webpack -w\" "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}`

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {                
                test: /.jsx$/,
                use:{
                    loader:'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_module/
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

#### app.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>                
                <h1>Mi Aplicacion React Js</h1>
                <h3>Probando la exportacion</h3>
            </div>
        )       
    }
}

export default App;
```

#### index.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './components/app.jsx';

render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('appStart')
)
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Aprendiendo React</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="appStart"></div>
        <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### resultado en consola

```
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\CursoReactJS\React_Scaffold> npm run dev

> prueba@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\PterPmntaM\CursoReactJS\React_Scaffold
> concurrently "node server.js" "webpack -w"

[0] Iniciando servidor
[1]
[1] Webpack is watching the files...
[1]
[1] Hash: 5fd2ce10b3c1788b385b
[1] Version: webpack 3.10.0
[1] Time: 4878ms
[1]     Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
[1] bundle.js  729 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
[1]   [14] ./src/index.jsx 381 bytes {0} [built]
[1]     + 27 hidden modules
```

Comment: index.jsx no necesita ser exportado? verifica todas las importaciones

Comment: @x-rw que mas, del ejemplo que me estoy guiando no exporta al final nada

Comment: el componente app.jsx le falta la importacion para renderizar import {render} from 'react-dom';

Comment: revisando si es eso,  sale bien comenta al respuesta para calificarte men, espera

Comment: @x-rw sigue igual, ve al chat a ver que podemos hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se producía debido a que estaba colocando mal la ruta en el `webpack.config.js`, ya que estaba de la siguiente forma

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {                
                test: /.jsx$/,
                use:{
                    loader:'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_module/
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Si se observa el path, esta `path: path.resolve('js')`, ya que no encontraba la ruta de forma correcta. Por lo cual la manera correcta según la estructura del proyecto seria

```
const path = require('path');

    const config = {
        entry: './src/index.jsx',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('public/js'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {                
                    test: /.jsx$/,
                    use:{
                        loader:'babel-loader'
                    },
                    exclude: /node_module/
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    module.exports = config;
```

forma correcta `path: path.resolve('public/js')`

[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738761/warning-react-createelement-type-is-invalid-bundle-js)